# Recommended group size for 1.5 years old?

Tags: toddler, daycare

We have a 1.5 year old boy. We are trying to choose between two daycare options - one is more intimate with 4-5 toddlers, 1-1.5 years old, the other is with about 10 kids, some will be older.

Are there any recommendations on group size for this age? I can only find information about adult-child ratio, which will be balanced in both places.

Comment: What is the adult-child ratio in both of these places? It may help to answer the question. Are these 2 places really similar otherwise? Or are there any other factors that are different, such as how good are the caretakers, turnover of staff, the care philosophy of the places (mainstream, Montessori, Waldorf, etc), the presence of a TV or other electronic devices, the quality of toys and educational materials, access to nature or at least a playground, air quality, etc.